# PHP print preview for popup display the link

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, popup

I'm using bootstrap for my popup window. The popup winodw works fine.

Here is the code

```
    <?php if(......my if condition for popup.......){ ?>
    <a data-target="#remoteModal" data-toggle="modal" href="popup.php?book_code=<?php echo $row['BookCode']; ?>&month=<?php echo $month; ?>">My PopUp Link</a>
    <?php } ?>
```

When I use print preview using File >> PrintPreview, the link is printed in the preview section. i.e the link is viewable ( popup.php?book_code=1&month=Apr )

How can I eliminate this?

First time i face this problem.

The print preview is like this

```
    S.No    Book Name       Book Code
    1       ABC             20
                            (popup.php?book_code=1&month=Apr )

    2       DEF             40                      
                            (popup.php?book_code=1&month=Apr )
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution here in this page

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/59900/how-to-get-rid-of-added-urls-when-printing-a-bootstrap-themed-page

May be this will be useful..

Just what i did is.. opened the bootstrap.css

Removed these lines from the css

```
a[href]:after {
content: " (" attr(href) ")";
}
```

This will surely help someone..

Thanks,
Kimz